# Error after publishing .net web project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, relative-path, publishing

I am publishing a project in my local computer, I am getting an error because of the path of the files, in my project I am using relative path, but when i published the project I specified a Site/application so I put: localhost/myapp, but then, after the login the additional name **myapp** make it loses the path references, do you have any idea how to go through this?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with my web application this problem occurs because in your application you are hardcoding paths for ex :- `/Home/Index` or something which creates problems whenever you want to provide paths use helpers like `@Url.Action()`,`@Html.Action()`,`@Url.Content()` as shown below :-

```
@Url.Action("Index","Home",new{//specify route parameters here//})
```

If you are using **areas** in you application then specify it as :-

```
@Url.Action("Index","Home",new { area="myarea" })
```